# Problems using DbUnit with Spring TestContext

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, junit, dbunit

I'm trying to test my DAO layer (which is built on JPA) in separation. In the unit test, I'm using DbUnit to populate the database and Spring Test to get an instance of ApplicationContext.

When I tried to use the SpringJunit4ClassRuner, the ApplicationContext got injected, but the DbUnit's getDataSet() method never got called.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/testdao.xml")
public class SimpleJPATest extends DBTestCase implements ApplicationContextAware {
    ...
```

Then I tried to remove the @RunWith annotation, that removed the problems with getDataSet() method. But now I no longer get ApplicationContext instance injected. I tried to use the @TestExecutionListeners annotation, which is supposed to configure the  DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener by default, but the AppContext still doesn't get injected.

```
@TestExecutionListeners
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/testdao.xml")
public class SimpleJPATest extends DBTestCase implements ApplicationContextAware {
    ...
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Is it generally a bad idea to combine these two frameworks?

---

EDIT: here is the rest of the source for the test class:

```
@TestExecutionListeners
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/testdao.xml")
public class SimpleJPATest extends DBTestCase implements ApplicationContextAware {

    static final String TEST_DB_PROPS_FILE = "testDb.properties";
    static final String DATASET_FILE = "testDataSet.xml";
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( SimpleJPATest.class );
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    public SimpleJPATest() throws Exception {
        super();
        setDBUnitSystemProperties(loadDBProperties());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSimple() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = ctx.getBean("entityManagerFactory", EntityManagerFactory.class);
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        GenericDAO<Club> clubDAO = new JpaGenericDAO<Club>(ClubEntity.class, "ClubEntity", em);
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Collection<Club> allClubs = clubDAO.findAll();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        assertEquals(1, allClubs.size());
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
         this.ctx = applicationContext;
    }

    private void setDBUnitSystemProperties(Properties props) {
        System.setProperty(PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_DRIVER_CLASS,
                props.getProperty("db.driver"));
        System.setProperty(PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_CONNECTION_URL,
                props.getProperty("db.url"));
        System.setProperty(PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_USERNAME,
                props.getProperty("db.username"));
        System.setProperty(PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_PASSWORD,
                props.getProperty("db.password"));

    }

    private Properties loadDBProperties() throws Exception {
        URL propsFile = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(TEST_DB_PROPS_FILE);
        assert (propsFile != null);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(propsFile.openStream());
        return props;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUpDatabaseConfig(DatabaseConfig config) {
        config.setProperty( DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY,
            new HsqldbDataTypeFactory() );
    }

    @Override
    protected DatabaseOperation getSetUpOperation() throws Exception {
        return DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT;
    }

    @Override
    protected DatabaseOperation getTearDownOperation() throws Exception {
        return DatabaseOperation.DELETE_ALL;
    }

    @Override
    protected IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception {
        logger.debug("in getDataSet");
        URL dataSet = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(DATASET_FILE);
        assert (dataSet != null);
        FlatXmlDataSet result = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(dataSet);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason why none of the DbTestCase methods get called is undoubtebly the fact that DbTestCase class uses JUnit 3.8 API and I'm trying to run in with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.

Comment: I've managed to use DbUnit with JUnit 4. This blog post helped me a lot (looking through the source of few key DbUnit classes didn't hurt either). http://ralf.schaeftlein.de/2009/01/05/dbunit-with-junit-4x-and-spring-for-testing-oracle-db-application/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used these two frameworks together without any issues.  I've had to do some things a little different from the standard though to get it to work:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext.xml" })
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class })
public class MyDaoTest extends DBTestCase {

@Autowired
private MyDao myDao;

/**
 * This is the underlying BasicDataSource used by Dao. If The Dao is using a
 * support class from Spring (i.e. HibernateDaoSupport) this is the
 * BasicDataSource that is used by Spring.
 */
@Autowired
private BasicDataSource dataSource;

/**
 * DBUnit specific object to provide configuration to to properly state the
 * underlying database
 */
private IDatabaseTester databaseTester;

/**
 * Prepare the test instance by handling the Spring annotations and updating
 * the database to the stale state.
 * 
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    databaseTester = new DataSourceDatabaseTester(dataSource);
    databaseTester.setDataSet(this.getDataSet());
    databaseTester.setSetUpOperation(this.getSetUpOperation());
    databaseTester.onSetup();
}

/**
 * Perform any required database clean up after the test runs to ensure the
 * stale state has not been dirtied for the next test.
 * 
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    databaseTester.setTearDownOperation(this.getTearDownOperation());
    databaseTester.onTearDown();
}

/**
 * Retrieve the DataSet to be used from Xml file. This Xml file should be
 * located on the classpath.
 */
@Override
protected IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception {
    final FlatXmlDataSetBuilder builder = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder();
    builder.setColumnSensing(true);
    return builder.build(this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("data.xml"));
}

/**
 * On setUp() refresh the database updating the data to the data in the
 * stale state. Cannot currently use CLEAN_INSERT due to foreign key
 * constraints.
 */
@Override
protected DatabaseOperation getSetUpOperation() {
    return DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT;
}

/**
 * On tearDown() truncate the table bringing it back to the state it was in
 * before the tests started.
 */
@Override
protected DatabaseOperation getTearDownOperation() {
    return DatabaseOperation.TRUNCATE_TABLE;
}

/**
 * Overridden to disable the closing of the connection for every test.
 */
@Override
protected void closeConnection(IDatabaseConnection conn) {
    // Empty body on purpose.
}
// Continue TestClass here with test methods.
```

I've had to do things a little more manual than I would like, but the same scenario applies if you try to use the JUnit Parameterized runner with Spring (in that case you have to start the TextContext manually).  The most important thing to note is that I override the closeConnection() method and leave it blank.  This overrides the default action of closing the dataSource connection after each test which can add unnecessary time as the connection will have to be reopened after every test.